# (Netty) Python client to Java server, ASCII to binary or hex

Tags: java, python, netty

I need to use python client to connect Netty server(base on JAVA).

Client:

```
UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 9999
MESSAGE = "16,01,12,03,1b,14,30,23,8000,03E8,0000,0000"
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

But the Netty server shows :

31 36 2c 30 31 2c 31 32 2c 30 33 2c 31 62 2c 31
   34 2c 33 30 2c 32 33 2c 38 30 30 30 2c 30 33 45
   38 2c 30 30 30 30 2c 30 30 30 30

It looks like "ASCII-hex"...

What should I do to make me get "16,01,12,03,1b,14,30,23,8000,03E8,0000,0000"
?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert the `ByteBuf` to a `String`. That said you will need to account for fragmentation as well as TCP does not guarantee that all will be received in one packet. For this you most likely want to prefix your message with some field which will tell you how long the message is.

For this you can use `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` in netty and then have it followed by a `StringDecoder`.